# If $f(x)$ is 2x differentiable in $(a,b)$ & $f'(a)=f'(b)=0$, prove that, $\exists\xi $ in $(a,b)$ S.T. $|f''(\xi )|\leq\frac{4(f(b)-f(a))}{(b-a)^{2}}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, proof-verification

Here is my argument (it doesn't feel 100% correct for some reason):

By the mean value theorem, there exists $\xi_{1}$ in $(a,b)$ such that,

$$f'(\xi_{1}) =  \frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}$$

Since, $f'(a)=f'(b)=0$, then by the mean value theorem again, there exists $\xi_{2}$ in $(\xi_{1},b)$ such that,

$$f''(\xi_{2})=\frac{f'(b)-f'(\xi_{1})}{b-\xi_{1}}=\frac{-(f(b) -f(a))}{(b-a)(b-\xi_{1})}$$

Since $\xi_{1}$ can be no lower than $a$,

$$f''(\xi_{2}) \geq \frac{-(f(b) -f(a))}{(b-a)^{2}} \, or\,  f''(\xi_{2}) \leq \frac{f(b) -f(a)}{(b-a)^{2}} \leq \frac{4(f(b) -f(a))}{(b-a)^{2}}$$

$$Assuming\, f(b)\geq f(a)$$

So it follows,
 $|f''(\xi_{2} )| \leq  \frac{4(f(b)-f(a))}{(b-a)^{2}}$?

Comment: You can use the Taylor formula twice $f(x)=f(a)+f'(a)(x-a)+f''(c)(x-a)^2/2$ for some $c\in (a, x)$ and  $f(x)=f(b)+f'(b)(x-b)+f''(c)(x-b.)^2/2$.

Comment: Thanks, your approach is valid. Was my approach correct though?

Comment: Your answer seems better than mine :) because I had $c_2-c_1$ term to be settled unless your question written incorrectly. I mean can the term $(b-a)^2$ could be $(b-a)^3$?

Comment: The textbook I am using is known to have a lot of typos, so with a grain of salt it should be $(b-a)^{2}$ since that's what's in the textbook :)

Answer (score 2):

As $f'(b) = f'(a)=0$, there is $y\in (a, b)$ such that $f''(y)=0$.

Comment: This is absolutely true! I think this might be the simplest proof for the given statement.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can use the Taylor formula twice $f(x)=f(a)+f'(a)(x-a)+f''(c_1)(x-a)^2/2$ for some $c_1\in (a, x)$ and  $f(x)=f(b)+f'(b)(x-b)+f''(c_2)(x-b.)^2/2$ for some $c_2\in (x, b)$. From here you can get $f(b)-f(a)=f''(c_1)(a-b)^2/2$ and $f(b)-f(a)=-f''(c_2)(a-b)^2/2$ and adding these you have $4(f(b)-f(a)=(f''(c_2)-f''(c_1))(a-b)^2$ and apply MVT to $f''(x)$ on $(c_1,  c_2)$ to have $f''(\xi)=\frac {f''(c_2)-f''(c_1)}{c_2-c_1}$.